# How to properly set up SRV records for ejabberd?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I'm trying to set up SRV records for my ejabberd server.
The domain I want to use to connect is, let's say, example.com and the server is hosted at server.example.com.

I've followed [this](https://prosody.im/doc/dns) guide and the records point perfectly to my server.
The thing is, when I try to connect from [Conversations](https://github.com/iNPUTmice/Conversations) (xmpp client) using the example.com domain, I get an error message saying "The server is not responsible for this domain".

I tried adding example.com as a host on the ejabberd config, but then I get a self-signed certificate, that shouldn't be happening since let's encrypt is configured. I also tried requesting a certificate for example.com, but I need a server runnning on that domain for the verification, which I think it's not the right solution.
Also, adding another host on the ejabberd config would be like creating another server?
Lastly, I also read [this](https://www.process-one.net/blog/how-to-configure-ejabberd-to-get-100-in-xmpp-compliance-test/) article, but it doesn't specify how to do it with another domain pointing to the server.

I want to be able to connect to my original server.example.com using only example.com, is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You are on the right track with "example.com" in the config. But you do need a valid certificate for example.com. It is true that this can be a little more fiddly to achieve with Let's Encrypt, as they don't support following SRV records. You can get around this in various ways, such as by using DNS verification instead of HTTP verification ( https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/ ) or by shipping a CSR and signing that on the other server.

Comment: @MattJ I added my domain to the hosts config, successfully got the certificates using DNS verification, and also added the certificates (fullchain and key) to the ejabberd config. But when I start the server, it tries to request new certificates for that domain, and every subdomain ejabberd uses (conference, proxy, pubsub, etc). Any idea on how to solve this?